# Issue with Portainer

Tags: docker, portainer

It works perfectly most of the time.
But sometimes it randomly gives the following error and does not work:

```
http error: Unable to initiate communications with endpoint (err=Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?) (code=500)
```

After restarting the container it works fine for some days, then gives the same error.

I searched about this problem and some people are facing this problem due to their docker installation version and portainer is not at all working.
But mine is working fine and only sometimes causing problems.

Have any of you faced similar issues?

Docker version is 18.09.7

Portainer version is 1.23.2

docker command:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_vol:/data portainer/portainer:1.23.2
```

docker version details:

```
Server:

Engine:

Version: 18.09.7

API version: 1.39 (minimum version 1.12)

Go version: go1.10.1

Git commit: 2d0083d

Built: Wed Aug 14 19:41:23 2019

OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently Portainer have newer version (2.0) with image tag portainer/portainer-ce:latest and docker have newer version 19.03, I think you can update both if you wanna get fixed bug or new features. after you upgrade the Docker you can run portainer with this command

```
 docker volume create portainer_data

 docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce
```

source: https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/linux/#docker-standalone